# Drag and drop open Windows from server to client and client to server

Tags: synergy, drag-and-drop, window-manager

I was wondering if their is a possibility within Synergy to drag open Windows (like Word or Excel) to the screen of the other system withing the Synergy setup. For example:

I'm working on an Excel sheet on my server, but I wish to move it to my other screen (the one of the client).

Is their anything within Synergy that can realize this?

Answer (score 3):

Nope - that is sadly not possible.

And it's doubtful it will ever be possible.

For that the exact same software with the exact same settings and the exact same files would need to be running on both machines, and some way of passing the open file and window settings between them would need to exist.

The closest that there will be is planned for Synergy v2 which is dragging and dropping of files between clients or clients and server.

Comment: what if you would just have the host computer run and render the program, then have it send the video output to the other computer and say "display this in a window" or "put this in (blank) object"

Comment: Then you wouldn't be running Synergy, you'd be running Windows Terminal Server, or Citrix.  The concept just doesn't exist in the Synergy setup.

Answer (score 0):

Synergy cannot do that, doing that requires a communication between your two windows managers and Synergy's only goal is to provide keyboard and mouse, not video as a KVM.

Solutions like RDP can do that though, see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Synergy 1.4.14 includes [drag and drop between computers (Windows and Mac)](http://synergy-foss.org/blog/synergy-1-4-14/)